# PHP - Facebook Error: No se puede cargar la URL

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-api

Estaba intentando realizar un login con facebook utilizando php para una aplicación web en la que estoy trabajando , logre hacer que funcionara en mi localhost entonces procedí a utilizar el IIS y obtuve un dominio para la aplicación pero al tratar de hacer login me da el siguiente error:

> ERROR: No se puede cargar la URL: El dominio de esta URL no está incluido en los dominios de la aplicación. Para poder cargar esta URL, agrega todos los dominios y subdominios de tu aplicación en el campo "Dominios de la aplicación" en la configuración de la aplicación.

El dominio que estoy utilization es redessociales.itsales.online y me asegure de que este estuviera en el campo designado para este en el panel de la aplicación de facebook

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código de mi login:

```
<?php

if(!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}

// Include the required dependencies.
require_once( 'vendor/autoload.php' );

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'app_id',
  'app_secret' => 'app_secret',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v3.1',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(
    'https://redessociales.itsales.online:444/fb/fb-callback.php',
    array('scope' => 'pages_show_list, manage_pages, publish_pages, user_photos'
));

echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($loginUrl) . '">Log in with Facebook!    </a>';
echo '<br>'
?>
```

Si alguien tiene una idea de que puede ser mi problema o de que estoy haciendo mal le agradecería que me lo hiciera sabe!

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Este error sucede cuando agregas los datos incorrectos cuando creas la  App en Facebook o cuando cambias las URL's de una App existente (esto ultimo cambia el ID de facebook y es lo que suele causar el problema). Revisa la configuración de la app aqui:

https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Seleccionas tu app y vas a la parte de  configuración básica.

Revisa que las URLs y las turas entesn correctas y apunten a tu sitio donde tengas el plugin de Facebook.

Comment: Originalmente la URL y los dominios apuntaban a un localhost que utilizaba para pruebas, será que es por eso que me da problemas ahora? Voy a tener que hacer otra app con las URL nuevas?

Comment: No, solo verifica los ID, probablemente cambiaron, solo debes reemplaarlos por los nuevos en tu archivo php

Comment: Parece que no cambiaron en lo absoluto